# jQuery Star Rating - Print Text on Click

Tags: jquery, hover, rating

Currently i'm using jQuery Star Rating plugin. The javascript code below shows the content from the title tag when hovering. When I stop hovering, the text (content) disappears. I want the text to stay when the user clicks one of the stars.

I found a piece of code below, which apparently prints the code in a DIV when clicking. 
Can anyone help me out how to intergrate that with the other code? It doesn't seem to work when I make a new script section.

**Code I'm using for the hover/title effect.**

```
jQuery(function($){  $('.hover-star1').rating({   focus: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('#hover-test1');
    tip[0].data = tip[0].data || tip.html();
    tip.html(link.title || 'value: '+value);   },   blur: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('#hover-test1');
    $('#hover-test1').html(tip[0].data || '');   }  });
```

**Code that apparently prints**

```
$('.hover-star').click(function (){$('#someDiv').text($(this).val());
```

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing bracket on the second line of code:

```
$('.hover-star').click(function (){$('#someDiv').text($(this).val());
```

should be

```
$('.hover-star').click(function (){$('#someDiv').text($(this).val() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the blur part in the rating function like this:

```
blur: function(value, link){
    var tip = $('#hover-star');
    $('#hover-test1').html($('input[name="someName"]:checked').attr('title') );
}
```

Replace "someName" by the name of the input field.
In addition, you can preset the value by adding outside of the rating function:

```
$('#hover-test1').html($('input[name="someName"]:checked').attr('title') );
```